# Why does my matplotlib histogram not look bell-shaped?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am plotting an image of sensordata. It is a 2D matrix of 2244x2116 containing small voltage values. I have plotted this data in Matlab and the result is as expected.

```
Data_filtered = DATA_File.Data
size(Data_filtered)

h = histogram(Data_filtered);
```

[image]

I exported the data to csv and plotted the data in matplotlib:

```
writematrix(Data_filtered, "C:\Users\_\DATA_File.csv")
data = r"C:\Users\_\DATA_File.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(data)

plt.hist(df)
plt.show()
```

The plot does not look like anything I would have expected. Does anybody have an idea what went wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How did you export the data? Please read [mre].

Comment: you have multiple colors so you are creating several plots. the most likely scenario is that you have a matrix and you are plotting a transposed version of your data.

Comment: Hi Cris, to export the data I used 
writematrix(Data_filtered, "C:\Users\_\DATA_File.csv")

Comment: You might try `plt.hist(df.to_numpy().ravel())` to convert the 2D dataframe to a 1D array suitable for `plt.hist()`.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, this is very likely. The plot in Matplotlib is rotated 90 degrees in comparison to the plot in Matlab. I have already tried df = df.transpose, but then I get errors when plotting. Which error depends on the plot I am creating. plt.imshow() -->"Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float". plt.hist()---> "object of type 'method' has no len()"

Comment: try creating a custom file with very few elements. debug your program and see how you data is imported. Then you will know what is wrong and how to solve it.

Comment: @JohanC, This did change the outcome and it looked like a snippet of the bell-shaped curve. After changing some settings, it looks familiar. Thanks everybody for your answers.

plt.xlim(-0.1, 0.1)
plt.ylim(0, 20000)

plt.hist(df.to_numpy().ravel(), bins=15000)